# How to exclude files / code blocks from code coverage with Netbeans / PHPStorm / PHPUnit integration

Tags: netbeans, phpunit, code-coverage, phpstorm

Requirements:

- Netbeans with PHPUnit(6.9)
- **EDIT:** Same applies, for example, to PHPStorm

How to:

- Exclude lines from code coverage.
- Exclude code blocks (lines) from code coverage.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you are trying to achieve 100% code coverage but have one or more lines that you cannot test, you can surround them with special annotations. They will be ignored in the code coverage report.

```
if (($result = file_get_contents($url)) === false) {
    // @codeCoverageIgnoreStart
    $this->handleError($url);
    // @codeCoverageIgnoreEnd
}
```

**Edit:** I have found that Xdebug often considers the closing brace to be executable. :( If that happens, move the end tag below it.

Comment: I had an old version of PHPUnit so that code did not work. I figured it out but thanks. Even a better solution is to use phpunit.xml => I post answer..

Comment: Confirmed with PHPStorm: need to move the end tag after the closing bracket.

Comment: Only problem with this is that the actual classes have ugly codecoverageignore blocks in them which I dont like

Answer (score 87):

To ignore method code blocks:

```
/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
function functionToBeIgnored() {
    // function implementation
}
```

To ignore class code blocks:

```
/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class Foo {
    // class implementation
}
```

And as @david-harkness said, to ignore individual lines:

```
// @codeCoverageIgnoreStart
print 'this line ignored for code coverage';
// @codeCoverageIgnoreEnd
```

More information can by found in the [PHPUnit Documentation](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/code-coverage-analysis.html#code-coverage-analysis.ignoring-code-blocks) under the **Ignoring code blocks** heading.

Answer (score 3):

First make sure you have the latest and greatest phpunit or else the code ignore might be missing. Next create a `phpunit.xml` file that looks something like this:

```
<phpunit colors="true">
    <filter>
        <blacklist>
            <file>file1.php</file>
            <file>file2.php</file>
        </blacklist>
    </filter>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: Your question asked about excluding lines and blocks which the above will not do--it ignores entire files. Also, if you use a whitelist (my company does), the blacklist is ignored.

Comment: Oops thanks David. This question was asked so long ago and in the title it says file. But thanks for the information.

Answer (score 0):

PHP unit 9.6,

If you want to ignore only one line :

```
public function buildTotalLssPrice(float $discount) : float
{
    switch ($this->getProductType()) {
        case ProductLicenseOption::ORDER_TYPE_LSS_ORDER_FORM_PRODUCT_IFS:
            return $this->buildTotalLssIfsPrice($discount);
        default:
            throw new Exception(sprintf("Not defined '%s'", $this->getProductType())); // @codeCoverageIgnore
    }
}
```