# NCover: Exclude unexecutable line of code from coverage

Tags: c#, unit-testing, code-coverage, ncover

The switch statement in following code has a `default` clause that is required by the compiler and a nice safeguard, but which is never executed. After writing tests for everything else, there is no way I can (or should) test that one line. I don't care that I haven't covered that line with tests, but my TestDriven.net NCover code coverage report does show the untested line and this causes the class coverage to drop to 86%. Is there a way to let NCover exclude just this one line?

```
public static class OperandTypeExtensions
{
    public static string ToShortName(this OperandType type)
    {
        #region Contract
        Contract.Requires<InvalidEnumArgumentException>(Enum.IsDefined(typeof(OperandType), type));
        #endregion

        switch (type)
        {
            case OperandType.None: return "<none>";
            case OperandType.Int32: return "i32";
            case OperandType.Int64: return "i64";
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```

My question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535157/how-do-i-test-code-that-should-never-be-executed), but none of the answers help in my specific situation.

Answer (score 3):

You can exercise it by casting integer value, which is not exists in OperandType enumeration to OperandType:

```
Assert.Throws<InvalidEnumArgumentException>(delegate { ((OperandType)Int32.MaxValue).ToShortName(); } );
```

BTW I see nothing bad in 86% coverage

UPDATE: There is no benefit of using `Contract` here. You will get exception anyway if value is not supported by your method.

```
public static class OperandTypeExtensions
{
    public static string ToShortName(this OperandType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case OperandType.None: return "<none>";
            case OperandType.Int32: return "i32";
            case OperandType.Int64: return "i64";
            default:
                throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```

And you should have `default`option here, because if new value will be added to `OperandType` enum, your `Contract` will allow that value, but switch will not support new option.

UPDATE2: If you really need 100% coverage and Contract for this method, then use OperandType.None as default option:

```
public static class OperandTypeExtensions
{
    public static string ToShortName(this OperandType type)
    {
        Contract.Requires<InvalidEnumArgumentException>(Enum.IsDefined(typeof(OperandType), type));

        switch (type)
        {
            case OperandType.Int32: return "i32";
            case OperandType.Int64: return "i64";
            default:
                return "<none>";
        }
    }
}
```

And add to your test assertion about enum:

```
CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(Enum.GetValues(typeof(OperandType)), 
                               new OperandType[] { OperandType.Int32,
                                                   OperandType.Int64, 
                                                   OperandType.None });
```

Comment: I cannot exercise it that way, as the contract will prevent me from putting any value in the method that I have not defined in the `OperandType` enumeration, which is as it should be. I'll get an `InvalidEnumArgumentException` and the line is still not covered.

Comment: Exactly, I should have `default`, as a safeguard (as stated). The contract surely has a benefit: the static checker can verify that no-one ever tries to put an undefined value in the method, and it adds to the documentation of the type. (Not specifying the `Contract` constraints on the parameters is like making all parameters be of type `object`).

Comment: I think it's overkill. Who will pass something different to your method, if it expects parameter of `OperandType`?

Comment: Maybe, I don't agree. But the point is that I want either to cover that `throw`, or ignore it, or some other creative solution. I just don't want to see it in my coverage results as it distorts the report.

Comment: +1 for your second update, adding a test that checks the enum matches what you expect

Answer (score -1):

*I also wanted to reach 100% for all my source files, not for the % but to avoid double checking every class every time I run the Code Coverage tool for false positive.*

In this case and IMO, if the **function is public** it means **you shall test it** with something similar :

```
Assert.Throws<NotSupportedException>( OperandTypeExtensions.ToShortName() );
```

---

**Other cases where it could occurs**

Usually, a bigger problem occurs when the function in which the `throws` or the `Debug.Assert` is private. In that case, sometimes the lines cannot be reached by tests. Or cannot be encapsulated in a `Assert.Throws`.

The only way I found to ensure every line is executed. **Far from ideal and very ugly**, I would have prefered a [comment annotation like that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4917471/62921) to disable it. Didn't work in C# though.

```
private string ToShortName(this OperandType type)
{
    var result = "";
    switch (type)
    {
        case OperandType.Int32: result = "i32";
        case OperandType.Int64: result = "i64";
    }
    Debug.Assert(result != "", "Invalid type.");
    return result;
}
```

With this solution, in your source code it will break before returning the empty string (in Debug) and Code Coverage will see the Debug.Assert line as executed.

*P.S. Although, I would like to know if there is a better solution, like annotation or something to disable specifically a code block.*